# How to detect business/weekend day in csv data

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv data, one column is representing timesteps (like 01.01.2010  01:15:00, every 15 minutes the next timestep comes) and in the second column there is data which represent the measurement at the timestep. Now I want to sort the data in business days and weekend to get a better representation.
Actually I have no idea how to start :(

Comment: please give us sample data to work on. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page. - Pandas  has some convenient [business day functionality](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read your csv into a dataframe using pandas framework.

Suppose your csv has data like this :

```
| record_timestamp    | reading |
|---------------------|---------|
| 01.01.2010 01:30:00 | 71      |
| 01.01.2010 01:45:00 | 97      |
| 01.01.2010 02:00:00 | 21      |
| 01.01.2010 02:15:00 | 64      |
```

You can read the csv file into a pandas dataframe using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd #import pandas

df = pd.read_csv('your_data_file.csv') # read csv as a dataframe
df['WEEKDAY'] = pandas.to_datetime(df['record_timestamp']).dt.dayofweek 
df["WEEKDAY"] = (df["WEEKDAY"] < 5).astype(float)
```